# Django Rest Framework: POST to Viewset with URL parameter

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Typically, in a DRF Viewset you might do something like this:

```
class FooViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    Foo-related viewsets.
    """
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]

    def list(self, request):
        """
        A list of foo objects.
        """
        context = {'request': self.request}
        queryset = Foo.objects.all()
        serializer = FooSerializer(queryset, many=True, context=context)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        """
        Get one publicly available Foo item.
        """
        context = {'request': self.request}
        queryset = Foo.objects.all()
        store_object = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = FooSerializer(store_object, context=context)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This works fine, and respectively correlates to:

`GET /foo` and `GET /foo/<pk>`. However, the last endpoint I need is `POST /foo/<pk>`. The problem here is that providing a `create` method to the views typically will be routed to `POST /foo`. Is there anything neat and elegant I can do from the ViewSet itself? Or is the only option basically to route `POST /foo/<pk>` to a specific one-off view?

Comment: Did my answer help to resolve your issue at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I would say in your `urls.py` for the REST endpoints you need:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '/foo',
        viewsets.FooViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create'}),
        name='Create Foo',
    ),
    path(
        '/foo',
        viewsets.FooViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}),
        name='List Foo',
    )
    path(
        '/foo/<pk>',
        viewsets.FooViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}),
        name='Retrieve Foo',
    )
]
```

It is convention to only `patch` (partial update) or `put` (update) to a `/foo/<pk>` endpoint.

Therefore, post to the base `/foo` endpoint, with a JSON deserialized representation of the object you want to create (minus the `pk`, let the DB create the `pk` on the fly).

If you want to update foo, then simply add:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path(
        '/foo/<pk>',
        viewsets.FooViewSet.as_view({'put': 'update'}),
        name='Update Foo',
    ),
    path(
        '/foo/<pk>',
        viewsets.FooViewSet.as_view({'patch': 'partial_update'}),
        name='Partially Update Foo',
    )
]
```

This would correspond to your FooViewSet as the following, as the most basic example as:

```
class FooViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        pass

    def create(self, request):
        pass

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        pass
```

Replacing each of the needed endpoints with the code you desire. Leaving in pass will disallow the method as well, which is handy if, for example, you wish to disable the destroy action on your API.

**Addendum**: It's worth adding you can also do the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '/foo',
        viewsets.FooViewSet.as_view({'post': 'custom_post_action'}),
        name='Create Foo',
    ),
```

With the corresponding in your `FooViewSet()`:

```
class FooViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    ...

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False, permission_classes=[SomePermissionClass], url_path='?', url_name='?')
    def custom_post_action(self, request):
        pass
```

If you wish, put I feel it may be bad practise and not truly representative of the "`RESTful`" principles, but who gives a CRUD if it's what you need?

Comment: This is interesting. So what I'm trying to do here is not to create an object, but to add an object of another type to the user's list. So we have `/notes` for example, I want to add this to the user's list at `POST /users/notes/<noteiD>`. Is this not a good way to do this ?

Comment: Although there is some linking between users and notes, I would probably organise it something more like `/users/<user_pk>/notes` to return all notes for a given `User`...so it sort of has hierarchical structure..then you can pass in the `pk` for the `User` to that endpoint...do you want me to add maybe a potential how to do this in my answer?

Comment: So in this case, these notes are all generic objects that may not necessarily be created by the user. Let's say I want to add a generic note (made by someone else) at `notes/<note_id>` to the current user's list of notes. How would I structure that route?

Comment: Hmmmm, so I would have a ownership relation for the notes....such that User A can create them. So a `ForeignKey` relationship between `Note` and `User` called `owner`. And then...potentially, a `ManyToMany` relationship between `Note` and `User` called somwething like `for`...

Comment: I would then structure the API such that you could have an endpoint just for `users/<user_pk>/notes/<note_pk>` ... but this isn't really RESTful in design as you have two pk `links`... as you will need to create quite the custom endpoint ... I would run with `/users/<user_pk>` which will have as the one of the fields a serialized list of note ids, then you can provide permissions on a note by note basis for the user to then view them. So custom `permission` class will be need `UserCanViewNote`, such that if you pass in the pk the currently logged in user can view that note...else 404 status.

Comment: What would be the RESTFUL way to do it? How would I add some generic item to a user’s collection of that item?

Comment: So. To add - you're looking at either an update or partial update to the user - adding anothing Note ID to the list of notes, is JSON format. This should then be parsed by the serializer and validated on save for a `ManyToMany` relationship field. You would need to have a note serializer that the user serializer references, and set `read_only` to `False`. e.g., `notes = NoteSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)`.